# How to configure twitter callback url in Spring Social 1.0.2?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-social

I need to configure callback url(redirect URL) ,in early spring social it configured as

---

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController">
    <!-- relies on by-type autowiring for the constructor-args -->
    <property name="applicationUrl" value="${application.url}" />
</bean>
```

Please tell how to configure in social 1.0.2 ,if have complete example please share.

Comment: Have you tried anything here?

Answer (score 0):

It is still the same. Check this [reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html) from springsource.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController">
<!-- relies on by-type autowiring for the constructor-args -->
<property name="applicationUrl" value="${application.url}" />
</bean>
```